# Simplified laser wakefield accelerator model

Tags: vectors, plasma-physics, accelerator-physics

so I am working on a summer essay and trying to work my way through the following online material I found; https://www.cockcroft.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/LWFA_comp.pdf.

However, there are some points I am unclear on page 11. Whilst assuming the density perturbation is uniform isn't too much of a struggle for me, basically, the problem is,

$(\pmb{v}.\nabla)\pmb{v} |--->\frac{ c^2}{2} \frac{\partial a^2 }{\partial z}$

where,

$a= v_{\perp}/c $

and everything is being linearised to the direction of propagation of the beam.
The issue arises when I write out the LHS like this,

$(v_{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + v_{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+v_{z}\frac{\partial}{\partial z})v_{z}$

I can't see where to get the RHS. However if I do this,

$\pmb{z}.\pmb{v}.\nabla \pmb{v}=\pmb{v}.\pmb{z}.\nabla\pmb{v}=\pmb{v}.(\frac{\partial \pmb{v}}{\partial z})=\frac{1}{2}\frac{ \partial v_{i}^2}{\partial z}$ (*),

I could then argue that a uniform $v_{z}$ results in the RHS, but I honestly don't  know if this is valid.

Tl:Dr - is (*) valid? If not anyone got any ideas?

Thank you.

P.s- in the slides, it's $v_{\perp}c$, but I think this is a typo as I have a book source that says otherwise.